# How to change the zeroes in tick labels

Tags: formatting, tikz-timing

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[dual arrows]{clockarrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
\nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
  0\cr
  \hidewidth
  \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
      \mathversion{bold}%
    \fi
    $\cdot\m@th$%
  }%
  \hidewidth
  \cr
  \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[scale=2,
timing/slope=0.1,
timing/rowdist=3ex,
]
\textnormal{\small Clock} &  [black] {h} 47{c} \\ 
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\tiny +5V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.south west){\tiny \pmzerodot};
\vertlines[help lines,red]{0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23}

\draw [->,>=latex] (0,-\nrows) -- (\twidth+1,-\nrows);
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,\twidth}
\draw (\n,-\nrows+.1) -- +(0,-.2)
node [below,inner sep=2pt] {\scalebox{.75}{ \textit{t}{$_{\n}$}}};

\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

And that I want output, all **zero**es are to be like `\pmzerodot`. Is it possible? I am waiting your help.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a font that includes the dot?

Comment: The difference in fonts between the `$t$`s and their subscripts doesn't help either (caused by the `\textit{t}{$_{\n}$}` setting the *t* in the body san-serif font and the subscript in maths mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little modular arithmetic:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[dual arrows]{clockarrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
\nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
  0\cr
  \hidewidth
  \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
      \mathversion{bold}%
    \fi
    $\cdot\m@th$%
  }%
  \hidewidth
  \cr
  \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\ScaledZeroDot{%
  \resizebox{\widthof{$\scriptstyle0$}}{\heightof{$\scriptstyle0$}}{$\pmzerodot$}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[scale=2,
timing/slope=0.1,
timing/rowdist=3ex,
]
\textnormal{\small Clock} &  [black] {h} 47{c} \\ 
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\tiny +5V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.south west){\tiny \pmzerodot};
\vertlines[help lines,red]{0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23}

\draw [->,>=latex] (0,-\nrows) -- (\twidth+1,-\nrows);
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,\twidth}
{
\pgfextra{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Modulo}{int(mod(\n,10))}%
  \ifnum\n=0\relax
      \gdef\MyNumber{\ScaledZeroDot}
  \else
    \ifnum\Modulo=0\relax
      \gdef\MyNumber{\pgfmathprint{int(div(\n,10))}\ScaledZeroDot}
    \else
      \gdef\MyNumber{\n}
    \fi  
  \fi
}
\draw 
  (\n,-\nrows+.1) -- 
  +(0,-.2)
  node[below,inner sep=2pt] 
  {\scalebox{.75}{ \textit{t}{$_{\MyNumber}$}}};
}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

A zoomed-in image showing one of the "new" zeroes:

[image]

Comment: Mine wouldn't come out the right size...

Comment: Do you know why mine works with `\zeroslash` but not the original? (It works, strictly speaking, but the zeros are too large.)

Comment: @cfr Let me check. However, I am confused. Which one is the "original"?

Comment: What I meant was that when I used `\pmzerodot` in my code rather than `\zeroslash`, the size of the dotted zeros was wrong. But with `\zeroslash`, I think the size is right. (Just these glyphs are slightly odd in Latin Modern and don't match the serif at all.)

Comment: @cfr You're right. Using `\pmzerodot` in your code, produces a dotted zero slightly bigger. I'd have to look at the code to see why. But I'll do it tomorro. It's almost bed time for me here.

Comment: That would be very kind. Thank you. It comes out wrong even if I put the `\ifnum...` inside the `\scalebox...`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I have some errors, Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!

Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Modulo` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Modulo}`, `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` no errors. It is working.

Comment: @Özgür That's weird. My code produces no errors in my system. Perhaps you are using a different version of PGF/TikZ? In any case, I'm glad you found a solution. I updated my answer scaling the `\pmzerodot`. The result is better now.

Comment: @cfr I don't know the cause of the problem. Perhaps it is in the definition of `\pmzerodot`? In any case, you could scale it down. In fact, I decided to do so also in my updated answer. The result is better now (I think), although the change is minimal.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for looking. I also tried a different definition for `\pmzerodot` from an alternative answer to the earlier question which concerned this. I think it used `stackengine`. Scaling it down is obviously an option. I'm just puzzled because I can't figure out what is causing it. Thanks again.