# If Numbers Contain Zeros, Change to Dotted Zeros

Tags: macros, formatting

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{calculus}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pst-node}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Dotted Zero
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
\nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
0\cr
\hidewidth
\kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
\raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
\if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
\mathversion{bold}%
\fi
$\cdot\m@th$%
}%
\hidewidth
\cr
\vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\dnm{12}
\newcommand\uyg{1}
\newcommand\uygkats{0,20}

\MULTIPLY{\dnm}{\uyg}\W
\MULTIPLY{\W}{\uygkats}\uygdvmsz
\ROUND[2]{\uygdvmsz}{\uygdvmsz}

\ROUND[0]{\uygdvmsz}\yuhaf
\INTEGERQUOTIENT{\yuhaf}{\uyg}\uhaf
\MODULO{\yuhaf}{\uyg}\usat

\begin{document}

\W\ $\cdot$ \uygkats\ = \uygdvmsz

\begin{center}
\opidiv[columnwidth=0.5em,operandstyle.2=\blue,resultstyle=\red]{\yuhaf}{\uyg}
\end{center}
{\color{red}\uhaf{}} week \usat{} hour
\end{document}
```

And output

[image]

That I want, all zeros are dotted zero. `\pmzerodot`. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Should the replacement of `0` with `\pmzerodot` happen throughout the document, or just when TeX is in math mode?

Comment: This does not look nice really, in my point of view

Comment: @Mico, `\newcommand\uygkats{0.2\pmzerodot}` >> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)   `\newcommand\uygkats{\pmzerodot.20}` >> Missing number, treated as zero

Comment: @Özgür - I'm afraid I don't understand how your comment relates to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what main font you are using. I tried your MWE and I detected by `\fontname\font` that you are using `cmr10 at10.95pt`. So, we prepare a virtual font `cmr10v` derived from `cmr10` font.

Do `cd` to the working directory where your document is. Then write the command:

```
tftopl cmr10 > cmr10v.vpl
```

Edit the newly created file `cmr10v.vpl`. Add the `MAPFONT` command after the line where is CHECKSUM:

```
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME cmr10)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   )
```

Find the definition of `CHARACTER C 0` and change this definition by:

```
(CHARACTER C 0
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.644444)
   (MAP
      (PUSH) (MOVEUP R 0.252) (MOVERIGHT R 0.114) (SETCHAR O 56) (POP)
      (SETCHAR C 0)   
      )
   )
```

Save this and run the command on command line:

```
vptovf cmr10v
```

Now, you have the files `cmr10v.vf` and `cmr10v.tfm` in the working directory. It means that the font `cmr10v` is ready to use in your working drectory.

Change the selecting of the main font from the original `cmr10 at10.95` to `cmr10v at10.95`. How to do this depends on the used font selection system. I hope that you will use a NFSS compliant way to do this. I don't want to spend my time of studying of NFSS then I suggest only simple `\reselectfont` macro:

```
\begin{document}
\def\reselectfont#1 #2\relax{\font\f=#1v #2\relax \f}
\expandafter\reselectfont\fontname\font\relax

% The test of your text follows:

\W\ $\cdot$ \uygkats\ = \uygdvmsz

\begin{center}
\opidiv[columnwidth=0.5em,operandstyle.2=\blue,resultstyle=\red]{\yuhaf}{\uyg}
\end{center}
{\color{red}\uhaf{}} week \usat{} hour
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: zerodot]

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
`\usepackage{lmodern}` added then I can't file `ec-lmr10v` What can I do?

Comment: Is it possible`10pt` or `12pt` instead of `11pt` ?

Answer (score 5):

Check out package [newtxtt](http://ctan.org/pkg/newtxtt)

```
\usepackage[zerostyle=d]{newtxtt}
```

and then `\texttt{0}` will typeset a dotted zero.

Comment: 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes. But not working.

Comment: @Özgür it may be overridden by later font commands -- does it work as the last line of your preamble in your MWE? What about deleting all auxiliary files (probably not required but always worth a shot)?

Comment: @ChrisH, I did it. Problem another packages.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`\0=\active
\newcommand\ifzero{20}
\newenvironment{specialzero}{%
\catcode`\0=\active\def 0{bla}}{}
% resetting the catcode when closing the environment is not needed
% as per Manuel's answer 
\catcode`\0=12

\begin{document}

\begin{specialzero}
0       
\ifzero
\end{specialzero}

0
% \ifzero %%%% This won't work!

\rule{10pt}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

However, when inside the `specialzero` environment, it is *not* possible to use the zero for any other purpose, e.g. as a parameter in a picture or another macro.

Comment: No need to reset at the end of the enviroment, since everything would be on a group.

Comment: Well observed, thanks.  I am generally too cautious. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PhilippImhof, I try your answer.

Comment: @PhilippImhof, Your code working, but `\newcommand\ifzero{20}` ...
`\begin{specialzero}
\ifzero
\end{specialzero}` not working. Still seeing dotless 20. What should we do?

Comment: Maybe it will be help, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255076/how-to-change-the-zeroes-in-tick-labels

Comment: You are absolutely right. My solution makes the zero an active character. If you make a zero without actually typing it, it won't (and cannot) work. You should definitely give more information on what you intend to do, because there will not be a single solution for *all* cases, e.g. why not define your `\ifzero` directly the way it is supposed to be? Or define the `\newcommand` while the zero is active (= inside the `specialzero` or in the preamble between the `catcode` changes).

Comment: @PhilippImhof, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240262/digit-zero-with-a-dot-inside-also-in-text-mode

Comment: I suggest you put the things clearer: What are you trying to achieve and in what context? It is nearly impossible to solve your problem without knowing more about it.