# Writing zeros with backslash natively

Tags: macros, catcodes

To avoid the general confusion with 0,O,o in general text, I am trying to define my own zero with a backslash within it (it also remains distinct from the `\emptyset` symbol or similar alphabets from other languages)

My MWE is:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \newcommand\0{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\textbackslash}{0}}
    \begin{document}
    There are 36\0 degrees in a circle.
    \end{document}
```

Now as you can see, I have to manually write \0 to get what I want. Is it possible to type normally with 0, and still get the equivalent of \0 in the text? I want to avoid using math mode as well.

P.S: Instead of backslash, I'm open to solutions which use zero with a `\cdot` in its centre.

Comment: Trust me: You don’t want to replace all occurrences of `0` with the degree symbol. This will break basically all TeX functionality.

Comment: @Gaussler the OP isn't suggesting using the degree symbol?

Comment: Not a backslash, but a dotted zero: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing and able to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document, there are lots and lots of OpenType system fonts that provide a "slashed" `0` natively. Note that some fonts provide a forward slash, while others provide a backward slash.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=SlashedZero}
\newcommand\blurb{360 degrees. 000.}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} 
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\blurb \quad\textsf{\blurb} \quad\texttt{\blurb}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} \blurb

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} \blurb

\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\blurb \quad\texttt{\blurb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use catcodes to make the required changes using the usual pdflatex. Xelatex nor lualatex seem to work well on my system for some reason.

Comment: @Miloop - Sorry, no idea. Maybe somebody else does.